# Eclipse p2 director install command behaving strangely different.Not working like before, changed the behavior

Tags: java, eclipse, p2

Eclipse p2 director install command behaving strangely different.Changed the behavior.

We have a Eclipse plug-in product, using p2 director install command since long time to install the zip file in target path of users installation directory. How ever it was not adding any related path in the 'Available Software Sites' section after installation, But 1 year before have noticed a bug. Given below.

During installation of the product the below command executes at first.

> "$INTV_ECLIPSE_DIR$$/$eclipse$/$eclipse.exe" -noSplash -application
>   org.eclipse.equinox.p2.director -repository
>   "jar:file:/$MS_NEW_SAR_STRING$/IC-P2-Repo.zip!/" -installIU
>   com.intervoice.common.tooling.feature.feature.group -destination
>   "$INTV_ECLIPSE_DIR$$/$eclipse"

After the product(Eclipse plugin) installed successfully, in `Eclipse -> Help -> Install New Software -> 'Available Softwares Sites'` section I see below.

> com.intervoice.gtf.p2repo
>   jar:file:/C:/Users/iviadmin/AppData/Local/Temp/170328.tmp/IC-P2-Repo.zip!/
>   Enabled

However the above name and location is not required to show there. My question is why it adds iviadmin users temp file path there, after installation. Earlier it was not behaving like this,this jar file path was not adding (jar and file path not required to display).Any Changes happened in ECLIPSE IDE in previous releases, which affected to the existing behavior of my tool when I upgraded to the next eclipse version.in a year or before in any Eclipse Wtp version upgradation??? Because before it was working fine.

Also please let me know, How could I suppress or remove this behaviour using p2 director command.

The below highlighted lines should not visible in the Available Software sites section , in ideal case. Screenshot below:

[image: Image of the error/bug]

the above command same as below

```
eclipse.exe -noSplash -application org.eclipse.equinox.p2.director -repository "jar:file:/D:/MyDownloads/com.intervoice.gtf.p2repo-3.0.0-SNAPSHOT.zip!/" -installIU com.intervoice.common.tooling.feature.feature.group -destination "C:/Program Files (x86)/Intervoice/Eclipse for Interaction Composer Studio 3.0/eclipse"
```

[Also the zip file (IC-P2-Repo.zip) is not located in the specified path.] com.intervoice.gtf.p2repo jar:file:/C:/Users/iviadmin/AppData/Local/Temp/170328.tmp/IC-P2-Repo.zip!/

I am using Eclipse Mars Eclipse Web Developer Tools Version: 3.8.0.v20160603 Eclipse Platform Version: 4.6.1.v20160907

Comment: Refer https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask before posting any question.

Comment: Do you get the same problem if you use `-roaming` in addition? You can remove the repository manually in the two files in the `p2/org.eclipse.equinox.p2.engine/.settings` folder.

Comment: Hey howlger, Even I use -roaming, the same problem persists. I can remove the same manually from eclipse 'Available Software Sites' by doing select and Remove.But I want to know, any p2 director command can be used to remove the location path, during installation. Any helpful command  to remove the below indicated path.   jar:file:/C:/Users/iviadmin/AppData/Local/Temp/170328.tmp/IC-P2-Repo.zip!

Comment: Any one please address my question and respond me earliest. This is quite priority for me.please let me know , how can I explicitly remove this entry(site name), from available software sites list, by using  p2 director commands to remove it pro-grammatically,I hope, This also can be helpful to solve my problem.Thank you.